# Trying to setup a webapp with mutliple authentication from powershell

Tags: claims

I want to set up a web application that can be accessed from three kind of authentication on the default zone:

- anonymous
- Windows
- FBA (over a custom provider)

and two other zones without the windows authentication.

I have this script :

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction 0

$defaultZoneUrl = "http://adm.local.mydomain.int"
$intranetZoneUrl = "https://local.mydomain.int"
$internetZoneUrl = "http://a.local.mydomain.int"

$winAp = new-SPAuthenticationProvider -UseWindowsIntegratedAuthentication -DisableKerberos
$anoAp = new-SPAuthenticationProvider -AllowAnonymous
$fbaAp = new-SPAuthenticationProvider -ASPNETMembershipProvider "CustMembershipProvider" -ASPNETRoleProviderName "CustRoleProvider"



$webApp = new-SPWebApplication -ApplicationPool "SharePoint - 80" `
                               -AuthenticationProvider $winAp, $anoAp, $fbaAp `
                               -DatabaseName "Wss_Content_Dev" `
                               -HostHeader "adm.local.mydomain.int" `
                               -Name "Dev web application" `
                               -Port 80 `
                               -SignInRedirectURL "/_layouts/cust/login.aspx" 

$intranetWebApp = new-SPWebApplicationExtension -AuthenticationProvider $anoAp, $fbaAp `
                                                -Identity $webApp `
                                                -Zone "Intranet" `
                                                -HostHeader "local.mydomain.int" `
                                                -Port 443 `
                                                -SecureSocketsLayer `
                                                -SignInRedirectURL "/_layouts/cust/login.aspx" 

$anoWebApp = new-SPWebApplicationExtension -AuthenticationProvider $anoAp, $fbaAp `
                                           -Identity $webApp `
                                           -Zone "Intranet" `
                                           -HostHeader "a.local.mydomain.int" `
                                           -Port 80 `
                                           -SecureSocketsLayer `
                                           -SignInRedirectURL "/_layouts/cust/login.aspx"
```

However, this breaks on the web application creation with the error :

```
New-SPWebApplication : Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.
Parameter name: provider
At E:\Scripts\SetupEnvironment\CreateWebAppAndZones.ps1:13 char:31
+ $webApp = new-SPWebApplication <<<<  -AllowAnonymousAccess `
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PWebApplication:SPCmdletNewSPWebApplication) [New-SPWebApplication], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSPWebApplication
```

I also tried but setting explicitely the flag `-AllowAnonymous` but the error remains.

When I go to the Central administration, my Web app is created, but is not claims enabled.

How can I correct my script to reach my goal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering myself...

I changed the script to perform these operations :

1. Create the webapp with only Windows Auth
2. Enable Claims authentication on the web app
3. Add the remaining auth providers
4. Extend the web app (passing all providers is working)

Here the updated script :

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction 0


$winAp = new-SPAuthenticationProvider -UseWindowsIntegratedAuthentication -DisableKerberos
$anoAp = new-SPAuthenticationProvider -AllowAnonymous
$fbaAp = new-SPAuthenticationProvider -ASPNETMembershipProvider "CustMembershipProvider" -ASPNETRoleProviderName "CustRoleProvider"



$webApp = new-SPWebApplication -ApplicationPool "SharePoint - 80" `
                               -AuthenticationProvider $winAp `
                               -DatabaseName "Wss_Content_Dev" `
                               -HostHeader "adm.local.mydomain.int" `
                               -Name "Dev web application" `
                               -Port 80 `
                               -SignInRedirectURL "/_layouts/cust/login.aspx" 

$webApp.UseClaimsAuthentication = $true
$webApp.Update()
$webApp.MigrateUsers($true)                               

Set-SPWebApplication -AuthenticationProvider $anoAp, $fbaAp -Identity $webApp -Zone "Default"   


$intranetWebApp = new-SPWebApplicationExtension -AuthenticationProvider $anoAp, $fbaAp `
                                                -Identity $webApp `
                                                -Zone "Intranet" `
                                                -HostHeader "local.mydomain.int" `
                                                -Port 443 `
                                                -SecureSocketsLayer `
                                                -SignInRedirectURL "/_layouts/cust/login.aspx" 

$anoWebApp = new-SPWebApplicationExtension -AuthenticationProvider $anoAp, $fbaAp `
                                           -Identity $webApp `
                                           -Zone "Intranet" `
                                           -HostHeader "a.local.mydomain.int" `
                                           -Port 80 `                                              
                                           -SignInRedirectURL "/_layouts/cust/login.aspx"
```