# Powershell to set a Web Application's Trusted Identity Provider to an STS and NTLM?

Tags: powershell, authentication, web-application

I've created a custom STS and have setup trust with SharePoint via `New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer`. I can use Central Admin to configure a Web Application to use both NTLM and the STS, however I can't do that via PowerShell.

Is there a PowerShell command to do that? `Set-SPWebApplication` has the **AuthenticationMethod** and **AuthenticationProvider** parameters, but if I specify both, only **AuthenticationProvider** is applied, i.e. Windows Authentication is unticked.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: This similar question might be of some help to you:

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34938/trying-to-setup-a-webapp-with-mutliple-authentication-from-powershell

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the fact you can comma separate authentication providers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case this helps anyone else (or me in the future) you can do this with:

```
$winAp = new-SPAuthenticationProvider -UseWindowsIntegratedAuthentication
$stsAp = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer "YourSTS"
Set-SPWebApplication -Identity $webApp -AuthenticationProvider $stsAp, $winAp -Zone "Default"
```